# Unit testing on device issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

From below link I found steps to perform unit testing,

[About Unit testing doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/00-About_Unit_Testing/about.html),
I can check testcases on simulator but can't run it on iOS device, there is one note like "Logic tests run only in simulators." but I have set Application tests.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

- It worked, there was an issue in target so I solved it. on my device OS is 5 and for unit test target was 6.so set it to 5. It's working now.